# Constraints for the -er affix

Tags: morphology, theoretical-linguistics

I was doing my homework and got stuck with questions iii and iv. The book doesn't contain information regarding these two questions and I don't know what applies here.

[image]

To me, it seems like:

iii)

(Column 1) -er is acceptable after stops and nasals (???)

(Column 2) -er isn't acceptable after a vowel/semivowel sound or liquid (???)

iv)
No, when -er means 'a person who does x' it doesn't apply. -> discove**r**er (liquid), ro**w**er (semivowel).

Does anybody have a clue about these answers?

Comment: I think you answered those questions to the best of your knowledge (within the given assignment).

Comment: It's simpler, actually. After phonetic consonants, _-er_ is OK in the locative sense; after phonetic vowels, it isn't. Final /r/ is a vowel in almost every dialect of English, so _Denver_ and _Delaware_ actually end in vowels. If there is a Scots dialect somewhere that has a trilled final /r/ (which I tend to doubt), maybe the rule would apply differently to these words.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. At first I thought it was indeed consonants vs. vowels, but then there was Denver and I couldn't get it out of the way. It actually makes sense to think of final /r/ as a vowel, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Final r isn't *always* a vowel.  My brother-in-law lives at Big Bear. @jlawler, and I don't think Delaware ends in a vowel, either.

Comment: A rhotic vowel, but (for me, DeKalb IL 1942) definitely a vowel. ['dɛlɨwɛ˞] and ['dɛ̧vɚ].

Comment: @jlawler You're the expert here, but my perception is that the 'r' in (say) 'center' is a vowel because it forms a second syllable, while the 'r' in 'bear' is just a consonant closing the (single) syllable. I'm referring to standard AmE in both cases.  How do you hear these two cases?

Comment: To my UK ears, it also depends on the number of syllables.  'Londoner' sounds fine [and is also long-established], but if I try to do this with 'Cardigan' [ends with the same unstressed syllable, but the name is one syllable longer] 'Cardiganer' sounds wrong.  But maybe this is because we don't so it with many place-names in England: 'New Yorker' sounds as familiar as 'Londoner', but I've never heard anyone from (old) York being called a Yorker.